# How to use dplyr to subset rows based on condition (By groups)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
ID   Date
ABC  2016-01-02
ABC  2016-03-03
ABC  2016-05-20
ABC  2016-07-30
ABC  2016-09-15
ABC  2016-10-02
ABC  2017-02-02
ABC  2017-04-02
ABC  2017-05-02
DDEF  2015-02-02
DDEF  2015-04-03
DDEF  2015-05-20
DDEF  2015-08-30
DDEF  2015-09-15
DDEF  2015-11-02
DDEF  2016-03-02
DDEF  2016-06-02
DDEF  2016-08-02
```

I only want those records (by group which) lie between the first date in a group and 365 days plus the first date (both included).

i.e.

```
    ID   Date
ABC  2016-01-02
ABC  2016-03-03
ABC  2016-05-20
ABC  2016-07-30
ABC  2016-09-15
ABC  2016-10-02
DDEF  2015-02-02
DDEF  2015-04-03
DDEF  2015-05-20
DDEF  2015-08-30
DDEF  2015-09-15
DDEF  2015-11-02
```

I had written a function which goes through each rows by group and flags then if the `Date` is less the first date in the group + 365 days.  but when the dataset is huge, it takes very long time. Is there a dplyr solution which can do it quicker?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Date <= Date[1L] + 365)`?

Comment: df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(as.Date(Date) <= first(as.Date(Date) + 365))

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Could you please put that as an answer? I would accept it.